# My query is returning duplicates

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, duplicates

I have written an SQL query to filter for a number of conditions, and have used distinct to find only unique records.

Specifically, I need only for the `AccountID` field to be unique, there are multiple `AddressClientIDs` for each `AccountID`.

The query works but is however producing some duplicates.

Further caveats are:

1. There are multiple trans for each `AccountID`
2. There can be trans record both `Y` and `N` for an `AccountID`

I only want to return `AccountIDs` which have transaction for statuses other than what's specified, hence why I used not in, as I do not want the 2 statuses.

I would like to find only unique values for the `AccountID` column.

If anyone could help refine the query below, it would be much appreciated.

```
SELECT AFS_Account.AddressClientID
    ,afs_transunit.AccountID
    ,SUM(afs_transunit.Units)
FROM AFS_TransUnit
    ,AFS_Account
WHERE afs_transunit.AccountID IN (
        -- Gets accounts which only have non post statuses
        SELECT DISTINCT accountid
        FROM afs_trans
        WHERE accountid NOT IN (
                SELECT accountid
                FROM afs_trans
                WHERE STATUS IN (
                        'POSTPEND'
                        ,'POSTWAIT'
                        )
                )
            -- This gets the unique accountIDs which only have transactions with Y status,
            -- and removes any which have both Y and N.
            AND AccountID IN (
                SELECT DISTINCT accountid
                FROM afs_trans
                WHERE IsAllocated = 'Y'
                    AND accountid NOT IN (
                        SELECT DISTINCT AccountID
                        FROM afs_trans
                        WHERE IsAllocated = 'N'
                        )
                )
        )
    AND AFS_TransUnit.AccountID = AFS_Account.AccountID
GROUP BY afs_transunit.AccountID
    ,AFS_Account.AddressClientID
HAVING SUM(afs_transunit.Units) > 100
```

Thanks.

Comment: Setting up a sqlfiddle would help to debug your issue. http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Also: which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Is it one to one relationship between two tables on this join: `AFS_TransUnit.AccountID = AFS_Account.AccountID` ?

Comment: @jpw No worries! I am guessing there is a one-to-many relationship between these two tables. So, I just wanted to confirm with the OP if this is true.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I'm using MS SQL Server.

Comment: @jpw - I need the multiple AddressClientIDs for each AccountID. As it's the unique field I need to remove the duplicates.

Comment: @FutbolFan - As you guessed one-to-many, the AccountID is used across multiple records in the TransUnit table.

Comment: @SolilquyOfChaos Please check out my updated answer below. I don't have a way to test that code, but hopefully that should work out for you!

Comment: @jpw Will post back tomorrow the desired output and update. Thanks

Comment: So an update, I tried @FutbolFan 's updated query from below, and it returns the exact same no. of rows as my original query.
So either my query is already working correctly & the duplicates are phantom, or I still need to change the query.

Further important caveats with regards to the schema.

AccountID and AddressClientID are bafflingly repeated in the afs_account table.  One addressclientID can have multiple AccountIDs which are unique, however one accountID can not have multiple AccountIDS. So i'm confused how I have any duplicates.

Comment: The query returns + 300k rows, I need to write a query now that finds the duplicate values from the result set. Only interested in finding duplicate values of the combination : addressclientID, AccountID.

Comment: AccountIDs are re-used when an account is closed, and reopened. This would create two records with the same accountID.
Also a customer may have two accounts, they will have different AccountIDS but the same AddressClientID. Eeeek!

Comment: @SolilquyOfChaos `AccountID and AddressClientID are bafflingly repeated in the afs_account table`. This is your reason for the duplicates as far as I can tell.

Comment: If you provide some sample data  along with your table strcuture, we can assist you better.

Comment: Closing this off now as I have removed all duplicates possible. The addressclientID is duplicated as it has different AccountIDs associated.
Confident that the solution from this thread now removes any other duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you confirmed that you have one-to-many relationship across two tables on `AccountID` column, you could use `Max` value of your `AccountID` to get distinct values:

```
SELECT afa.AddressClientID
    ,MAX(aft.AccountID)
    ,SUM(aft.Units)
FROM AFS_TransUnit aft
INNER JOIN AFS_Account afa ON aft.AccountID = afa.AccountID
GROUP BY afa.AddressClientID
HAVING SUM(aft.Units) > 100
    AND MAX(aft.AccountID) IN (
        -- Gets accounts which only have non post statuses
        -- This gets the unique accountIDs which only have transactions with Y status,
         -- and removes any which have both Y and N.
        SELECT DISTINCT accountid
        FROM afs_trans a
        WHERE [STATUS] NOT IN ('POSTPEND','POSTWAIT')
            AND a.accountid IN (
                SELECT t.accountid
                FROM (
                    SELECT accountid
                        ,max(isallocated) AS maxvalue
                        ,min(isallocated) AS minvalue
                    FROM afs_trans
                    GROUP BY accountid
                    ) t
                WHERE t.maxvalue = 'Y'
                    AND t.minvalue = 'Y'
                )
        )
```

Comment: @SolilquyOfChaos I believe you might want to tweak some of your not in queries. I will post that shortly with my suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT AFS_Account.AddressClientID
    ,afs_transunit.AccountID
    ,SUM(afs_transunit.Units)
FROM AFS_TransUnit
INNER JOIN AFS_Account ON AFS_TransUnit.AccountID = AFS_Account.AccountID
INNER JOIN afs_trans ON afs_trans.acccountid = afs_transunit.accountid
WHERE afs_trans.STATUS NOT IN ('POSTPEND','POSTWAIT')
    -- AND afs_trans.isallocated = 'Y'
GROUP BY afs_transunit.AccountID
    ,AFS_Account.AddressClientID
HAVING SUM(afs_transunit.Units) > 100
and max(afs_trans.isallocated) = 'Y' 
and min(afs_trans.isallocated) = 'Y'
```

Modified your query with ANSI SQL join syntax. As you are joining the tables, you just need to specify the conditions without using the sub-queries you have.

Comment: This query is functionally different from the original and won't return the same results.

Comment: Thanks, however I need to return results only for AccountIDs where only IsAllocated is set to Y. An AccountID can have multiple transactions, for which they can be Y and N.

Comment: so if an accountid has a 'Y' and 'N', it should not be in your results..is that correct?

Comment: @vkp That's right. There for instance may be 10 records for an AccountID in trans table, 9 may be Y, but 1 as N. I don't want these AccountIDs.

Comment: modified to include the conditions in `having` clause. see if it works.